# In JMeter, why do i get better response times at higher throughput?

Tags: jmeter

I ran a simple test on one of my api's initially with 1000 threads for 10 secs and then with 100 threads for 10 secs. Why is the response time better at higher throughput as i thought it should be other way round?

[image: JMeter]

[image]

Comment: Do you use a keep-alive ? If yes then try without, results should be more or less equal .